# redux gets two errors in React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I want to create a cart for a shopping mall,
when I use the **redux** ,which always comes two errors(Problem A&B).

Problem A.

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Problem B.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1650:1)
    at Provider (Provider.js:12:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

As the photo below:
[image]

Data structures:

```
cartRedux>>store>>index.js
useSelector>>Nav.jsx(which shows the console.log() )
```

here are my relative data:

**cartRedux.js**

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const cartSlice=createSlice({
    name:"cart",
    initialState:{
        products:[],
        quantity:0,
        total:0,
    },
    reducers:{
        addProduct:(state,action)=>{
            state.quantity+=1;
            state.products.push(action.payload.product);
            state.total+=action.payload.price;
        },
    }
})
export const {addProduct}=cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

**store.js**

```
import {configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./cartRedux";

export default configureStore({
    reducer:{
        cart:cartReducer,
    }
})
```

**index.js** and the error always metioned the **Provider**,but it is imported from react-redux.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from './redux/store';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#root'));
root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
);
```

Nav.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import Styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = Styled.div` 

width:100%;
color: black;
height:max-content;
`;


const Nav = () => {
    const cart=useSelector(state=>state.cart)
    console.log(cart);
    return (
        <Container/> .....
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Comment: Where and how do you call useMemo ?

Comment: @GasparCdv I checked it but I didn’t use it.It’s in Provider js,which is imported from react-redux

Comment: This is probably because you have two versions of react installed, if you are using yarn you can do `yarn why react` and you might find the issue there

Comment: @Anna You're able to solve this issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was here facing the same challenge for the whole day. The cause is absolutely due to different versions of react running in your same project.  To solve it, I simply created a new project in a separate folder and it is now working well.

Comment: Please add more information, such as commands used, relevant documentation, etc.